Evaluating a Difference of Trace Powers of Self-Adjoint Bounded Operators using Only the Spectrum
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert Space. Let $A$ be a bounded, self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H}$ with purely continuous spectrum and let $B$ be a trace-class, self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal{H}$. For $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$, consider the trace $\mathrm{Tr}((A+B)^n-A^n)$.
Since $B$ is trace class and the set of trace class operators is an ideal in the set of bounded operators, $(A+B)^n-A^n$ is trace class. So, this trace is well-defined and finite.
Is there a way to deduce this trace using only this spectral decomposition of $A+B$ and $A$? Specifically, according to the spectral theorem, a bounded self adjoint operator is unitarily similar to to a multiplication operator on a direct sum of real measure spaces (See Reed-Simon Theorem VII.3 or this question). Can you compute this trace knowing only these measure spaces but not the corresponding unitary transformation?
This is clearly is possible if $A$ is compact and self adjoint, as $A+B$ and $A$ would both have countable spectra, letting us write the trace as $\mathrm{Tr}((A+B)^n-A^n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\lambda_k(A+B)^n-\lambda_k(A)^n$, where $\lambda_k(O)$ denotes the k-th largest eigenvalue in the spectrum of $O$. But its not clear how this idea could generalize to a continuous spectrum?
For an example, consider $\mathcal{H}=\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Define $A$ and $B$ as
$$Au_k=u_{k+1}+u_{k-1},$$
$$Bu_k = \delta_{k,0}u_k.$$
Could we deduce that $\mathrm{Tr}((A+B)^2-A^2)=1$ and $\mathrm{Tr}((A+B)^4-A^4)=9$, using only the spectral decomposition of $A+B$ and $A$?
